# Restrict remote access to folder inside tomcat webapp folder

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have Spring Boot micro-service based application hosted on Tomcat 9. So, I have multiple folders deployed in {{tomcat root dir}}/webapps folder. I want only one folder to be accessible from outside network (gateway service). Others folder should be accessible only from localhost.

So, how can I achieve this without adding context.xml? I know this can be achieved by adding context.xml but context.xml is getting overwritten after every war deployment.

So want to check if this can be achieved at more global level like modifying server.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valves must be defined in a `<Context>` section, but adding a `META-INF/context.xml` to your application is not the only way to [define a context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

If you want to restrict most applications to localhost, the easiest way is to modify `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`:

```xml
<Context>
    ...
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"" />
</Context>
```

or `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/context.xml.default` (usually `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/context.xml.default`) if you wish the changes to apply only to a single host.

Every web application context will inherit the `<Valve>`s in the aforementioned files. Since you want to have a web application (let's say `/pubApp`) without these restrictions you need to create a file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/pubApp.xml` and set the `override` attribute to `true`:

```xml
<Context override="true">
    <!-- Remember to copy all configuration values from `conf/context.xml`
         and `conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/context.xml.default`
         that you wish to apply, since they will not be read anymore.
     -->
    ...
</Context>
```

Comment: I updated $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml and added valve to restrict remote connections and it worked. Now all requests from remote are being blocked. However, when I created a file common-service.xml inside /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost and added 
<Context override="true" antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow=".*" /></context>. all requests are still getting blocked. its not getting overriden

Comment: common-service is my gateway service which I want to be accessible from remote. Can you check where I am doing wrong

Comment: Check the logs: when you start tomcat you should see a line like `Deploying configuration descriptor [.../conf/Catalina/localhost/common-service.xml]` instead of `Deploying web application directory [.../webapps/common-service]`. In your comment you use `</context>` instead of `</Context>`, hence the XML is not well formed.